# Bean property is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter? Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am developing `Spring Batch CompositeItemReader & Writer` Example. I developed XML file and able to compile code successfully, but when running mu sample code gives me following error. Not sure what is going wrong?

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'customerNumber' of bean class [java.lang.String]: Bean property 'customerNumber' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:619)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:610)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor.extract(BeanWrapperFieldExtractor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.ExtractorLineAggregator.aggregate(ExtractorLineAggregator.java:54)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter.write(FlatFileItemWriter.java:267)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:175)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:151)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.write(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:274)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:199)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:198)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:162)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:141)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:304)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
    at com.common.batch.main.CompositeMain.main(CompositeMain.java:24)
```

jdbc-composite-item-reader-job.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:context-datasource.xml" />

    <!-- JobRepository and JobLauncher are configuration/setup classes -->
    <bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean" />

    <bean id="jobLauncher"  class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>


    <!-- Step will need a transaction manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />


    <!-- =========================================================== -->    
    <job id="compositeJdbcReaderJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <step id="compositeJdbcReaderStep" next="compositeJdbcReaderStep2">
            <tasklet>
                <chunk reader="compositeItemReader" writer="itemWriter" commit-interval="5" />
            </tasklet>
        </step>

        <step id="compositeJdbcReaderStep2">
            <tasklet>
                <chunk reader="compositeItemReader2" writer="itemWriter2" commit-interval="5" />
            </tasklet>
        </step>
    </job>


    <!-- ============= Composite Item Reader ================ -->
    <bean id="compositeItemReader" class="com.common.batch.reader.CompositeCursorItemReader">
        <property name="unifyingMapper">
            <bean class="com.common.batch.mapper.DefaultUnifyingStringItemsMapper" />
        </property>
        <property name="cursorItemReaders">
            <list>
                <ref bean="itemReader1" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="compositeItemReader2" class="com.common.batch.reader.CompositeCursorItemReader">
        <property name="unifyingMapper">
            <bean class="com.common.batch.mapper.DefaultUnifyingStringItemsMapper" />
        </property>
        <property name="cursorItemReaders">
            <list>
                <ref bean="itemReader2" />                 
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <!-- ========== ItemReader =============== -->
    <bean id="itemReader1" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="saveState" value="true" />

        <property name="sql">
            <value>
                <![CDATA[ ${select.sql.customers} ]]>
            </value>
        </property>
        <property name="rowMapper">
            <bean class="com.common.batch.mapper.CustomerMapper" />
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="itemReader2" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="saveState" value="true" />

        <property name="sql">
            <value>
                <![CDATA[ ${select.sql.employees} ]]>
            </value>
        </property>
        <property name="rowMapper">
            <bean class="com.common.batch.mapper.EmployeeMapper" />
        </property>
    </bean>


    <!-- ============= Flat File Writters ============= -->
    <bean id="itemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter" scope="step">
        <property name="resource" value="${output.file.location}" />
        <!-- <property name="appendAllowed" value="true" /> -->
        <property name="lineAggregator">

            <!-- An Aggregator which converts an object into delimited list of strings -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">

                <property name="delimiter" value="|" />
                <property name="fieldExtractor">
                    <!-- Extractor which returns the value of beans property through reflection -->
                    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                        <property name="names" value="customerNumber,customerName,contactLastName,contactFirstName,phone,addressLine1,
addressLine2,city,state,postalCode,country,salesRepEmployeeNumber,creditLimit" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>

        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="itemWriter2" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter" scope="step">
        <property name="resource" value="${output.file.location}" />
        <property name="appendAllowed" value="true" />
        <property name="lineAggregator">
            <!-- An Aggregator which converts an object into delimited list of strings -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">

                <property name="delimiter" value="|" />
                <property name="fieldExtractor">
                    <!-- Extractor which returns the value of beans property through reflection -->
                    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                        <property name="names" value="employeeNumber,lastName,firstName,extension,email,officeCode,reportsTo,jobTitle" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Employee.java

```
public class Employee implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer employeeNumber;
    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
    private String extension;
    private String email;
    private String officeCode;
    private Integer reportsTo;
    private String jobTitle;
    // setters and getters
}
```

Customer.java

```
    public class Customer implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer customerNumber;
    private String customerName;
    private String contactLastName;
    private String contactFirstName;
    private String phone;
    private String addressLine1;
    private String addressLine2;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String postalCode;
    private String country;
    private Integer salesRepEmployeeNumber;
    private Double creditLimit;


    public Integer getCustomerNumber() {
        return customerNumber;
    }
    public void setCustomerNumber(Integer customerNumber) {
        this.customerNumber = customerNumber;
    }
    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }
    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }
    public String getContactLastName() {
        return contactLastName;
    }
    public void setContactLastName(String contactLastName) {
        this.contactLastName = contactLastName;
    }
    public String getContactFirstName() {
        return contactFirstName;
    }
    public void setContactFirstName(String contactFirstName) {
        this.contactFirstName = contactFirstName;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    public String getAddressLine1() {
        return addressLine1;
    }
    public void setAddressLine1(String addressLine1) {
        this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
    }
    public String getAddressLine2() {
        return addressLine2;
    }
    public void setAddressLine2(String addressLine2) {
        this.addressLine2 = addressLine2;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
    public String getPostalCode() {
        return postalCode;
    }
    public void setPostalCode(String postalCode) {
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
    }
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    public Integer getSalesRepEmployeeNumber() {
        return salesRepEmployeeNumber;
    }
    public void setSalesRepEmployeeNumber(Integer salesRepEmployeeNumber) {
        this.salesRepEmployeeNumber = salesRepEmployeeNumber;
    }
    public Double getCreditLimit() {
        return creditLimit;
    }
    public void setCreditLimit(Double creditLimit) {
        this.creditLimit = creditLimit;
    }
    /*@Override
    public String toString() {
        return customerNumber + "|" + customerName + "|" + contactLastName + "|" + contactFirstName + "|" + 
                phone+ "|" + addressLine1 + "|" + addressLine2 + "|" + city + "|" + state+ "|" + postalCode + "|" + 
                country+ "|" + salesRepEmployeeNumber + "|" + creditLimit;
    }*/
}
```

CompositeMain.java

```
public class CompositeMain {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("composite/jdbc-composite-item-reader-job.xml");

        JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
        Job job = (Job) context.getBean("compositeJdbcReaderJob");

        JobExecution execution;
        try {
            execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
            System.out.println("Job Exit Status : "+ execution.getStatus());

        } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException
                | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException | JobParametersInvalidException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Done !!");
    }
}
```

My DB details:

```
mysql> desc customers;
+------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| customerNumber         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| customerName           | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| contactLastName        | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| contactFirstName       | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| phone                  | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| addressLine1           | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| addressLine2           | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| city                   | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| state                  | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| postalCode             | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| country                | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| salesRepEmployeeNumber | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| creditLimit            | double      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
13 rows in set (0.14 sec)

mysql> desc employees;
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| employeeNumber | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| lastName       | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| firstName      | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| extension      | varchar(10)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| email          | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| officeCode     | varchar(10)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| reportsTo      | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| jobTitle       | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I see issue is already there: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/112929-concurrent-problem-with-beanwrapperimpl-getpropertyvalue-in-3-1

pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <springframework.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <springbatch.version>3.0.1.RELEASE</springbatch.version>
        <mysql.version>5.1.31</mysql.version>
        <joda-time.version>2.8</joda-time.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring XML to/back object -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Batch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springbatch.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
            <version>${springbatch.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>${joda-time.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

CustomerMapper.java

```
public class CustomerMapper implements RowMapper<Customer>{

    @Override
    public Customer mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setCustomerNumber(rs.getInt("customerNumber"));
        customer.setCustomerName(rs.getString("customerName"));
        customer.setContactLastName(rs.getString("contactLastName"));
        customer.setContactFirstName(rs.getString("contactFirstName"));
        customer.setPhone(rs.getString("phone"));
        customer.setAddressLine1(rs.getString("addressLine1"));
        customer.setAddressLine2(rs.getString("addressLine2"));
        customer.setCity(rs.getString("city"));
        customer.setState(rs.getString("state"));
        customer.setPostalCode(rs.getString("postalCode"));
        customer.setCountry(rs.getString("country"));
        customer.setSalesRepEmployeeNumber(rs.getInt("salesRepEmployeeNumber"));
        customer.setCreditLimit(rs.getDouble("creditLimit"));

        return customer;
    }
}
```

EmployeeMapper.java

```
public class EmployeeMapper implements RowMapper<Employee>{

    @Override
    public Employee mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setEmployeeNumber(rs.getInt("employeeNumber"));
        employee.setLastName(rs.getString("lastName"));
        employee.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstName"));
        employee.setExtension(rs.getString("extension"));
        employee.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
        employee.setOfficeCode(rs.getString("officeCode"));
        employee.setReportsTo(rs.getInt("reportsTo"));
        employee.setJobTitle(rs.getString("jobTitle"));

        return employee;
    }
}
```

CompositeCursorItemReader.java

```
public class CompositeCursorItemReader<T> implements ItemStreamReader<T> {

    private List<AbstractCursorItemReader<?>> cursorItemReaders;

    private UnifyingItemsMapper<T> unifyingMapper;

    @Override
    public T read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
        // read from all registered readers
        List items = new ArrayList();
        for (AbstractCursorItemReader<?> cursorItemReader : cursorItemReaders) {
            items.add(cursorItemReader.read());
        }
        // delegate to mapper
        return unifyingMapper.mapItems(items);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(ExecutionContext executionContext) {
        for (ItemStream itemStream : cursorItemReaders) {
            itemStream.update(executionContext);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws ItemStreamException {
        for (ItemStream itemStream : cursorItemReaders) {
            itemStream.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
        for (ItemStream itemStream : cursorItemReaders) {
            itemStream.open(executionContext);
        }
    }

    public void setUnifyingMapper(UnifyingItemsMapper<T> mapper) {
        this.unifyingMapper = mapper;
    }

    public void setCursorItemReaders(List<AbstractCursorItemReader<?>> cursorItemReaders) {
        this.cursorItemReaders = cursorItemReaders;
    }
}
```

UnifyingItemsMapper.java

```
public interface UnifyingItemsMapper<T> {
    T mapItems(List<?> items) throws Exception;
}
```

Comment: have you actually the getters and setters in `Customer.java` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring is trying to get the property `cutomerNumber` from the `String` class :

```
 Invalid property 'customerNumber' of bean class [java.lang.String]
```

which is wrong because the `String` is not supposed to be configured as the `item` of your job 's step, the `Item` in this context is supposed to be the `Customer`.

your beans are configured correctly except for one bean :`compositeItemReader`

The read method of this bean is returning a `String` instead of a `Customer` which is because of this :

```
public class CompositeCursorItemReader<T> implements ItemStreamReader<T> {

/** Registered ItemStreamReaders. */
private List<AbstractCursorItemReader<?>> cursorItemReaders;
/** Mandatory Unifying Mapper Implementation. */
private UnifyingItemsMapper<T> unifyingMapper;

@Override
public T read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
    // read from all registered readers
    List items = new ArrayList();
    for (AbstractCursorItemReader<?> cursorItemReader : cursorItemReaders) {
        items.add(cursorItemReader.read());
    }
    // delegate to mapper
    return unifyingMapper.mapItems(items);
}
}
```

Its property UnifyingMapper is configured as follow:

```
  <property name="unifyingMapper">
                <bean class="com.common.batch.mapper.DefaultUnifyingStringItemsMapper" />
      </property>
```

here is the implementation of the `UnifyingItemsMapper` you are using:

```
 public class DefaultUnifyingStringItemsMapper implements UnifyingItemsMapper<String> {

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public String mapItems(List<?> items) throws Exception {
        if (items != null && items.size() > 0) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (Object item : items) {
                if (item != null) {
                    sb.append(item);
                }
            }
            if (sb.length() > 0) {
                return sb.toString();
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

the solution to this is to create a new Class that implements `UnifyingItemsMapper<Customer>` and configure it for your `CompositeCursorItemReader#unifyingMapper`

Or just use your `itemReader` directly if you don't need a `UnifyingItemsMapper`:

```
 <job id="compositeJdbcReaderJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <step id="compositeJdbcReaderStep" next="compositeJdbcReaderStep2">
            <tasklet>
                <chunk reader="itemReader1" writer="itemWriter" commit-interval="5" />
            </tasklet>
        </step>

        <step id="compositeJdbcReaderStep2">
            <tasklet>
                <chunk reader="itemReader2" writer="itemWriter2" commit-interval="5" />
            </tasklet>
        </step>
    </job>
```

Comment: @javatechnology you are welcome can you mark it as an answer ?

Comment: @javatechnology why do you need this class DefaultUnifyingStringItemsMapper ??

Comment: As per your answer, we're not using CompositeCursorItemReader API, I wanted to read through this API. I will mark the answer accepted too. Hoping to read though CompositeCursorItemReader API, I added CompositeCursorItemReader<T>

Comment: @javatechnology `CompositeCursorItemReader` is meant to be used when you have more than one Reader , and that method is meant to unify bothe reader's output on just one common output, I guess you don't need it on this scenario

Comment: No,  I want to use that CompositeCursorItemReader to read for more than one reader, this is what I actually wanted to implement, but your answer makes the things simple. In future I wanted to read data from 50 tables and write to one file or to separate files. How we can implement CompositeCursorItemReader for each Custom object ?

Comment: @javatechnology it is an OOP desing , make your models Implements an interface in which it contains , getterrs & setters for common fields between all objects , then in the mthod use inheritance to retun that common object.

Comment: Ok thank you for nice info! how we can achieve this in this code?

Answer (score 2):

You declare your class Customer as:

```
public class Customer implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer customerNumber;
    private String customerName;
    private String contactLastName;
    private String contactFirstName;
    ....
    // setters and getters
}
```

All of your fields are private and you have not yet implemented public getter/setter methods. Do that and your issue will be solved.